# Warning: Visiting this site may harm your computer!

Tags: google-chrome, mozilla

Hai guys,
         I own a site it was working fine but when i hit my site now in firefox or google chrome i got this error Warning: Visiting this site may harm your computer!.... I dont know how to get rid of this....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you got blacklisted for a reason.  check your site really well:

- get tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/), open your page in web browser and make sure requests sent from your computer go just to your site [ or trusted 3rd party sites ]
- open all index.html/php in text editor, turn on wrapping and search for rogue javascript / html code.
- check content of .htaccess files and make sure they do not contain any malicious rewrite / redirection rules

there is a plague of programs stealing passwords from ftp clients and uploading rough html / javascript / .htaccess files.

or maybe you just got hacked / are victim of js/html injection to your cms.

Comment: I would include Google Webmaster Tools in the list of recommendations. After all you can reasonably expect that the data used by Google Chrome to produce warnings to also be used by Google Webmaster Tools. Google want to help webmasters get rid of malware, and Google Webmaster Tools is the place they can inform webmaster directly about such issues.

Answer (score 1):

I actually notified a friend of mine the other day that her site got blacklisted the same way. I looked through the source code on her index and she had shady looking obfuscated javascript in her head tag. I think this is generally the reason this happens. Someone compromised your website and you need to find where the problem is as soon as possible.

Comment: marcin i removed everything but when i hit my page it got black listed how to remove it ?

Comment: So it was rogue javascript? In order to fix this so you are no longer blacklisted, read this 

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=45432

After you follow the directions there, and google looks through your site and verifies the malware is gone, they will remove you from the blacklist. You should also read through this blog entry:

http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2009/10/show-me-malware.html