# How to remove my site from blacklist of google chrome and mozilla

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, malicious

Hai guys,
         I removed all malicious code from my website pages and javascript files but still i cant view my site in firefox and google chrome.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered this question in your already posted question.

[Warning: Visiting this site may harm your computer!](https://serverfault.com/questions/86908/warning-visiting-this-site-may-harm-your-computer)

In order to fix this so you are no longer blacklisted, read this

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=45432

After you follow the directions there, and google looks through your site and verifies the malware is gone, they will remove you from the blacklist. You should also read through this blog entry

http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2009/10/show-me-malware.html